# Reactor Netty - how to send with delayed Flux

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

In Reactor Netty, when sending data to TCP channel via `out.send(publisher)`, one would expect any publisher to work. However, if instead of a simple immediate `Flux` we use a more complex one with delayed elements, then it stops working properly.
For example, if we take this hello world TCP echo server, it works as expected:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.netty.DisposableServer;
import reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Reactor1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DisposableServer server = TcpServer.create()
            .port(3344)
            .handle((in, out) -> in
                .receive()
                .asString()
                .flatMap(s ->
                    out.sendString(Flux.just(s.toUpperCase()))
                ))
            .bind()
            .block();
        server.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
}
```

However, if we change `out.sendString` to

```
out.sendString(Flux.just(s.toUpperCase()).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
```

then we would expect that for each received item an output will be produced with one second delay.

However, the way server behaves is that if it receives multiple items during the interval, it will produce output only for the first item. For example, below we type `aa` and `bb` during the first second, but only `AA` gets produced as output (after one second):

```
$ nc localhost 3344
aa
bb
AA <after one second>
```

Then, if we later type additional line, we get output (after one second) but from the previous input:

```
cc
BB <after one second>
```

Any ideas how to make `send()` work as expected with a delayed `Flux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't recreate publisher for the `out.sendString(...)`
This works:

```
DisposableServer server = TcpServer.create()
        .port(3344)
        .handle((in, out) -> out
                .options(NettyPipeline.SendOptions::flushOnEach)
                .sendString(in.receive()
                        .asString()
                        .map(String::toUpperCase)
                        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))))
        .bind()
        .block();
server.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Comment: Yeah, starting with `out` makes sense (combined with `flushOnEach`). In the [document](https://violetagg.github.io/reactor-netty-workshop/#_creating_tcp_server) referenced from the reactor-netty page, they do have a single TCP example which has `handle` that starts with `in` and then `flatmap`. But looking at HTTP examples, they always use the style starting with `out` (`res`).

Comment: I realized one thing in this answer doesn't work properly: it uses `delayElements` operator on a single stream, which will delay all responses equally, instead of each individually. For example, if there is first input at t1=0, and second at t2=100ms, instead of expected outputs at t1=1000ms and t2=1100ms, it would produce outputs at t1=1000ms and t2=2000ms. However, with a small change it can work properly: we just have to replace `.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` with `.flatMap(s -> Mono.just(s).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))))` - it will delay each element individually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [concatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-). This works:

```
DisposableServer server = TcpServer.create()
        .port(3344)
        .handle((in, out) -> in
                .receive()
                .asString()
                .concatMap(s ->
                        out.sendString(Flux.just(s.toUpperCase())
                                           .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                ))
            .bind()
            .block();
server.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Delaying on the incoming traffic

```
DisposableServer server = TcpServer.create()
        .port(3344)
        .handle((in, out) -> in
                .receive()
                .asString()
                .timestamp()
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .concatMap(tuple2 ->
                        out.sendString(
                                Flux.just(tuple2.getT2().toUpperCase() +
                                        " " +
                                        (System.currentTimeMillis() - tuple2.getT1())
                                ))
                ))
        .bind()
        .block();
```

Comment: There is one issue with this: `concatMap` will subscribe to the next inner publisher only after the previous one is completed, which messes up the timing: given the first input at t1=0, and second at t2=100ms, instead of expected outputs at t1=1000ms and t2=1100ms, it would produce outputs at t1=1000ms and t2=2000ms

Comment: Then move the `.delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))` before `concatMap` so that I will delay the consumption of the incoming traffic. The important thing here is that Reactor Netty do not allow nesting the send operation, which will happen if you use [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: This gives the same results, it always produces outputs at the interval boundary (1s). Given that having multiple `send` operations in flight is not allowed, I wonder if "in.receive, out.send" style is ever useful, compared to the "out.send, in.receive" style (as in the accepted answer) which also seems easier to reason about since there is a single out stream.

Comment: I updated my answer with delaying on the incoming data + `timestamp()`. When I make a request, I receive: `aa
ss
ddAA
1005
SS
1343DD
1714` That's just for completeness of the answer otherwise the style `send(receive)` in the previous answer is better than receive then multiple send operations however it depends on the use case.